# jQuery Datatables merge?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using the jQuery data plugin, and with initialising my page, I do an AJAX call to fill the table. Then, every 1.5 seconds I do another AJAX call to get the new info, I then clear the table, and fill it again.

Is there a way for me to check if the new JSON from the new AJAX call is different to the current, and then edit **just** those cell(s) to the new value, so I don't have to completely refresh my table every time?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you refreshing the table? You make it sound like it's an arduous task, but should be as simple as calling `draw()`.  What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: These are my 2 JSON objects: http://pastebin.com/nB4zDgcR ; Basically, what I am trying to achieve is, there is some different data in there, the very first object in both vars is different. Number 31 is the id. With 31 all texts inverted (Decline => Accept and Accept => Decline). Now I need to update this in the table, without it completely refreshing which messes my searchboxes up (if I type and it refreshes after 1,5 seconds, it resets the input).

Comment: I understand. You could certainly parse the json and use jquery to update the cells, but I'm not sure how you'd update the underlying datatable without redrawing it, which as you say would reset the search box. Could you create your own search box? i.e. not use the default datatables search control?

Comment: That would be a possibility indeed. I am not sure if draw() resets the search boxes since I couldn't get it to work. What I am doing now is: $('#table').dataTable().fnClearTable(); and then $('#table').dataTable().fnAddData(data); (which is what resets it)

Comment: Actually, I don't think it does clear the searchbox, As you're using v1.9 you need to use `fnDraw()`.  It depends on how you're populating the datatables though - can you show the initialisation code please?

Comment: Ofcourse. This is how I initialize it at first: [Click](http://pastebin.com/J14LMwDe). And then I edit it this way: [Click](http://pastebin.com/53aqh3tL). And I want to replace the editing part in a way it doesn't refresh the code.

Comment: The way you're populating the datatable means you can't use `fnDraw()`.  If you used [sAjaxSource](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side#sAjaxSource) instead you could then use `fnDraw()` but I'm not 100% sure it would solve your problem.  Worth a try though.

Comment: I can't use sAjaxSource since Async needs to be false. My only option is to use IE7, which doesn't like Datatables default ajax function.

Comment: ah ok, sorry I can't help you more - hope you find a solution.

Comment: It turned out I was a tiny bit dumb. Because in the interval (in the doAll() function), I re-adding the searchboxes, hence why they reset. So in the end, my old way worked, it was just that the searchboxes kept getting re-added.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/w8khwc1e/

Comment: The way I got it now seems to work aswell. I also can't use JSON.Stringify because IE7 is bad.